# Write custom raw query of mysql using nestjs framework

Tags: mysql, nestjs

Here is the example using sequeilizejs :

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(users => {

  })
```

How to write custom raw query of mysql using nestjs framework?

Answer (score 3):

You can write raw queries in nestjs with sequelize using the syntax below.

this._productModel.sequelize.query("SELECT ...", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});

Answer (score 1):

Never used sequelize, but I assume you could create a database service that wraps the sequelize instance/methods and use it from there. Maybe you can [take a look at my example with pg](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/database/database.service.ts) and see if it helps.

Comment: Slightly off topic - where would you write RAW sql queries? Service? Or would you create a separate Data Access layer ( just as its common .NET or java) ?

Comment: Right now I have them written in the feature.service.ts, but I'm thinking about moving the queries out a level to a mapper level and keep the service clean

Comment: do you have any git repos I could take a look at for best practices? NestJs.

Comment: The one I linked above

Answer (score 0):

For a start point you can look at this tutorial: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-sequelize

But instead
this.CATS_REPOSITORY.findAll();
you should use something like that
this.CATS_REPOSITORY.sequelize.query('SELECT ...');

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `this._productModel.sequelize.query("SELECT ...")` approach. Here is another way without Model:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly sequelize: Sequelize,
    // @InjectModel(User)
    // private readonly userModel: typeof User,
  ) {}

  async findAll() {
    const [users] = await this.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM users;');
    return users as User[];
  }
}
```